# For the point inside circle, find in which quarter it is?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I researched google but couldn't find the keywords for search. So I ask here if my algorithm and code is efficient?

http://sketchtoy.com/66429941 (algorithm)

The algoritm is: I have four points which are: north, east, south and west of circle. I check 4 distances (distanceToNorth, distanceToEast, distanceToSouth, distanceToWest). And I find minimum of them so that is the quarter.

Here is the code but it does not seem efficient for me. 
(firstQuarter is North, secondQuarter is East and so on..

note: assume that mousemove is inside the circle.

```
var firstQuarterX = centerX;
var firstQuarterY = centerY - radius;
var secondQuarterX = centerX + radius;
var secondQuarterY = centerY;
var thirdQuarterX = centerX;
var thirdQuarterY = centerY + radius;
var fourthQuarterX = centerX - radius;
var fourthQuarterY = centerY;

var distanceToFirst = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-firstQuarterX, 2) + Math.pow(y-firstQuarterY, 2));
var distanceToSecond = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-secondQuarterX, 2) + Math.pow(y-secondQuarterY, 2));
var distanceToThird = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-thirdQuarterX, 2) + Math.pow(y-thirdQuarterY, 2));
var distanceToFourth = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-fourthQuarterX, 2) + Math.pow(y-fourthQuarterY, 2));

var min = Math.min(distanceToFirst, distanceToSecond, distanceToThird, distanceToFourth);

var numbers = [distanceToFirst, distanceToSecond, distanceToThird, distanceToFourth];

var index = numbers.indexOf(min); // it will give 0 or 1 or 2 or 3

var quarter = index + 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the boundaries between your quarters lie along the lines with equations `y = x` and `y = -x`, relative to an origin at the center of the circle.  You can use those to evaluate which quarter each point falls in.

If your point is (`x`, `y`), then its coordinates relative to the center of the circle are `xRelative = x - centerX` and `yRelative = y - centerY`.  Then

- your point is in the first (south in your code) quarter if `yRelative < 0` and `Math.abs(xRelative) < -yRelative`
- your point is in the second (east) quarter if `xRelative > 0` and `Math.abs(yRelative) < xRelative`
- your point is in the third (north) quarter if `yRelative > 0` and `Math.abs(xRelative) < yRelative`
- your point is in the fourth (west) quarter if `xRelative < 0` and `Math.abs(yRelative) < -xRelative`

I leave it to you to determine to which quarter to assign points that fall exactly on a boundary.  Also, you can implement a little decision tree based on those criteria if you prefer; that should be a little more efficient then testing each criterion in turn.

Comment: this seems best. just a few lines unlike mine.

Comment: I used this, I got the logic, Thanks everyone

Comment: I like the idea to do this without atan2() - fast, precise, with least numerical issues. Beside of the numerical issues in floating point arithmetic, remember that Pi is nothing you can expose with a finite number of (decimal) digits. (That's why it got its own specific.)

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure but I think this might work. `Math.atan2(CenterY - y, CenterX - x) * 180 / Math.PI` gives the apparent angle between the points. Do the remaining math to figure out the quarter.

Comment: By remaining math, I mean computing the ranges (0-90, 90-180..) in which the resulting angle lies. Glad you got it.

Comment: according to my project, first quadrant is 45-135.

Comment: Yeah well then the ranges change, nothing else ;)

Comment: I dont know why ( my geometry lacks ). but minus of your formula gave the right angle. var angle = - (Math.atan2(mouseY - centerY, mouseX - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI); So it worked

Comment: It worked because in the 'actual geometry', quadrants run anti clockwise! Fun fact right?!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
return x>centerX?(y>centerY?"Quad 2":"Quad 1"):(y>centerY?"Quad 3":"Quad 4");
```

Less graceful, more slim.

Comment: That would work if the quadrant borders were parallel to the axes

Comment: Looking his initialization it looks so!

Answer (score 0):

For more efficient algorithm, you can compute the quadrant just by analyzing the signs of dx + dy and dx - dy quantities (dx, dy being x, y minus centerX, centerY respectively) (I presume that as your animation shows, your quadrants are rotated by 45 degrees against 'standard' quadrants.

Comment: My code is more complex but i didnt copy here whole code. It is working btw.